# asp.net adding ApiController as service for dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

Hello I went off [this guide](http://scottdorman.github.io/2016/03/17/integrating-asp.net-core-dependency-injection-in-mvc-4/) to integrate asp.net core Dependency Injection into MVC 5. Originally it worked fine using a default controller (Inherited from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` class). But then I wanted the injected dependency to be available in an controller that inherited from `System.Web.Http.ApiController`. I'm 95% sure the problem is coming from this part of the code where all the controllers are added as services since I'm getting the same error as the guide says I will get without it that portion.

> a missing method exception saying that your constructor doesn’t implement the default parameterless constructor

### Startup.cs

```
public static class ServiceProviderExtensions
{
   public static IServiceCollection AddControllersAsServices(this IServiceCollection services,
      IEnumerable<Type> controllerTypes)
   {
      foreach (var type in controllerTypes)
      {
         services.AddTransient(type);
      }

      return services;
   }
}

public partial class Startup
{
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    PackageScraperService pScraper = new PackageScraperService();
    services.addSington<IPackageScraper>(pScraper);

    // Problem Code

    services.AddControllersAsServices(typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
     .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
     .Where(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t) 
        || t.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
  }

  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app){
      var services = new ServiceCollection();

      ConfigureServices(services)
      var resolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver(services.BuildServiceProvider());
      DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);
  }
}
```

I have looked at the results of

```
typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
     .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
     .Where(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t) 
        || t.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

and it appears to correctly find my ApiController (ValuesController.cs)

I also changed my api controller to inherit from the `Controller` class and it worked fine.

Is there a simpler way to add a controller as a service? I've had a incredibly hard time finding documentation for this since I'm using MVC instead of Core.

Comment: Web api uses a different dependency resolver. Not seeing you setting that one up. The guide linked will only work for MVC controllers

Comment: Ah ok is it possible to use Microsoft's dependency resolver or will I have to use Unity etc.. for web api?

Comment: just like how you have to create a wrapper resolver for mvc you have to do the same for Web API. `IDependencyResolver` exists for web api as well but in a different namespace. you then set the resolver for the GlobalConfiguration

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update to include `ApiControllers`

```
services.AddControllersAsServices(typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
     .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
     .Where(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t) 
        || typeof(IHttpController).IsAssignableFrom(t));
```

You will also need to set the dependency resolver for the Web API global configuration.

Update the `DefaultDependencyResolver` so that it can be used by both MVC and Web API. They share an interface by name but they belong to different namespaces.

```
public class DefaultDependencyResolver :
    System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver,
    System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver {

    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public DefaultDependencyResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }    

    public object GetService(Type serviceType) {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType) {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetServices(serviceType);
    }

    //Web API specific

    public System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyScope BeginScope() {
        return this;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        // NO-OP, as the container is shared. 
    }
}
```

And in start up you set the resolver for both MVC and Web API.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app){
    var services = new ServiceCollection();    
    ConfigureServices(services);        
    var resolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver(services.BuildServiceProvider());
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);//Set MVC
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver; //Set for Web API
}
```

Comment: Spent a long time looking for a solution here. Ripped out Unity on an older web app in favor of the Core DI libraries and my ApiControllers weren't working. Just needed that last line. Thank you!