# Registering Transient Web API Controller with IServiceProvider leads to outofmemoryexception

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I've seen numerous examples for setting up a .NET Framework Web API using the DI libraries built for .NET Core (i.e. IServiceProvider). While it all makes sense, I am seeing memory issues with my Web API Controllers. A description of this setup is shown here.

[asp.net adding ApiController as service for dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691211/asp-net-adding-apicontroller-as-service-for-dependency-injection#)

IServiceProvider uses transient tracking and keeps a list of all disposables. Because the ApiController base class implements IDisposable and is setup as a Transient dependency, the list of disposables will grow indefinitely as subsequent requests are made to each controller. This will create a severely large memory problem. Transient tracking is talked about here.

https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/456

My question is what is the proper way to register these controllers with the container so memory will not spiral out of control?

I need to use IServiceProvider and cannot use a third-party DI framework.

I have tried to register controllers as scoped, but receive the following error. Any help would be appreciated.

[Scoped controller error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPTQw.png)

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to instantiate a class implementing IDependencyScope from the BeginScope() method in the DependencyResolver. This prevents a new pointer from being added to the Disposables collection and thereby eliminates the memory leak.

```cs
/// <inheritdoc />
public class DefaultDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public DefaultDependencyResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetServices(serviceType);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new DefaultDependencyScope(_serviceProvider.CreateScope());
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //No-op
    }
}

/// <inheritdoc />
public class DefaultDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
{
    private readonly IServiceScope _serviceScope;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public DefaultDependencyScope(IServiceScope serviceScope)
    {
        _serviceScope = serviceScope;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _serviceScope.Dispose();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetServices(serviceType);
    }
}
```

and then register the dependency resolver from the API configuration

```cs
        //Register controllers with container
        foreach (var type in typeof(WebApiConfig).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            .Where(t => typeof(ApiController).IsAssignableFrom(t)))
        {
            services.AddTransient(type);
        }

        //Link DI in application to container
        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        config.DependencyResolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver(provider);
```

In my case, I didn't NEED to register any dependencies as singletons. If this is required, there may be additional code needed to conditionally return a scope based on the type.